# What to render to html form If I need to send multiple (hidden) values with the same key?

Tags: html

Let's say I have got a form with only one visible input (a checkbox for instance) and I need to send the value of that input along with an array of ids that identifies objects that should be modified based on the value of that visible field, i.e. POST data should look something like this:

```
active=1
ids=1
ids=2
ids=3
...
ids=1000
```

I know that I can render 1000 hidden inputs for each id in ids array. But isn't there a better way (that avoids generating so much markup)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not how many inputs with the same name are sent. In reality, you're going to get something more like this:

```
ids=1,2,3,4
```

It should be pretty easy to build this value in Javascript. In fact, why do you care how the POST data is sent? Just build a string of values, send it and parse it on the server :)

Or are you using some kind of server that *expects* to get 100 POST values with the same key? I thought the contract was that the key should be unique? Checkboxes work that way in plain HTML...

Comment: keys does not need to be unique (e.g. select multiple) and ye, I have a backend function that expects the 1000 POST values (even though I could also use comma separated list format but I would need to modify some stuff cause of that)

Comment: @clime: I'd go with the comma separated list anyway. Even just sending the extra "ids=" all the time sounds completely wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Name each of your hidden inputs like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="array_input[]" value="1" />
```

Then on the php side use $_POST['array_input'] as ordinary array

```
  print_r($_POST['array_input']);
```